# How can I get all email addresses from all tables in one query

Tags: sql, database

I want to get all email addresses from all tables(whatever column name is and whatever table name is) in one query. Is It possible, If yes then how?

Comment: yes, it is possible. vague question...vague answer :)

Comment: :) but I want to know, How is it possible, I edited my question

Comment: Do you *know* the names of the tables and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT email FROM table1
UNION
SELECT email FROM table2
```